# Solr query how to read grouped values?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm trying to group my documents but I don't understand how to make a combined query.
Example:

```
<doc1>
<id>1</id>
<myid>1</myid>
<name>test</name>
</doc1>

<doc2>
<id>2</id>
<myid>1</myid>
<name>test2</name>
</doc2>
```

When I group on myid I get only 1 group result which is excepted. But I wonder how I could get a list of the names with that group.

something like:

```
<Response>
<doc>
<id>1,2</id>
<myid>1</myid>
<name>test1,test2</name>   //this
</doc>
```

The query I'm using:

```
        SolrQuery sq = new SolrQuery();
        sq.setQuery("*:*");
        sq.setStart(0);
        sq.setRows(100);
        sq.setParam("group", true);
        sq.setParam("group.field","myid");
```

**I don't know how to read the groupresponse to get the name values for that grouped item?**

I noticed there's an option to set group.limit and group.offset which allow me to get multiple results. But I'm still wondering if its possible to get a list of the 'name' fields. I think I need to facet name on the group results but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Solr source code 
Refer to the `QueryResponseTest.java` JUnit and `testGroupResponse()` method

[SOLR-2637](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2637) is applied 3.4 onwards.

Check out the patch [SOLR-2637.patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12488314/SOLR-2637.patch) also.

Comment: I'm using a build version of 3.6.x is that patch included?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2637 is available form 3.4 onwards so should work.